# How to execute a PS script that uses remoting from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I have a series of fully functional powershell scripts that leverage remoting that I want to be able to call from a C# WinForm.  Here's the code I have so far

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        _runspace.Open();
        _ps = PowerShell.Create();

        _ps.Runspace = _runspace;

        var output = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
        output.DataAdded += DataAdded;

        _ps.AddScript(@"C:\projects\Acme\trunk\PowerShell\deploy-qa-p5.ps1");
        _invokeResult = _ps.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output);

    }
```

When I run this code, I see that any powershell commands in my script that are meant to execute against a remote session are actually being executed on my local PC.

For example, this bit of code when executed directly from Powershell.exe, uninstalls an application from a remote server.  When run from the C# code above, this same code uninstalls said application **on my local machine**:

`Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession  -scriptblock $uninstallScript  -ArgumentList $applicationGuid`

Again, the exact same PS script referenced in my C# code, when executed directly from powershell.exe, works as expected against the remote server.

Via googling, I found how one can create a remote runspace from C#.  However, that would require me to refactor my PS scripts substantially to pull out any remoting code, which would be moved to C#. Since I still need to be able to run my PS scripts in standalone mode (i.e. directly from powershell.exe), this is not a viable solution.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem that doesn't require re-jiggering my PS scripts?

Comment: Check if you have you `$remoteSession` when running from C#. I'm using `Invoke-Command` from C#, but use `-ComputerName` instead of `-Session` and it's working just fine for me

Answer (score -1):

When you create the `Runspace` object, you need to pass it a `WSManConnectionInfo` object to create a remote runspacen.  This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has details on how to do this.  Unlike the example in this topic, make sure you use a WSManConnectionInfo constructor that takes parameters that allow you to specify the remoting endpoint e.g.

```
_runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace("http://ComputerName:5985/wsman");
```

Sorry, I misread the question.  Calling a script that happens to perform remoting should work just as well as when calling from a PowerShell console.  The following slightly modified version works just fine for me on my home workgroup:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    _runspace.Open();
    _ps = PowerShell.Create();

    _ps.Runspace = _runspace;

    var output = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
    //output.DataAdded += DataAdded;

    var netCreds = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Keith", Settings.Default.Password);
    var creds = new PSCredential(netCreds.UserName, netCreds.SecurePassword);

    _ps.AddScript("param($creds) Invoke-Command -cn Kids-PC -Scriptblock {hostname} -Credential $creds").AddArgument(creds);
    _invokeResult = _ps.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output);
    _invokeResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    _ps.EndInvoke(_invokeResult);
    textBox1.Text = output[0].ToString();
}
```

BTW not sure why you added `DataAdded` to the output collection for the script? I commented that out. I also have to pass along credentials since I'm on a workgroup and not a domain.

In order to debug this, when it fails take a look at the _ps.Streams.Error object in the debugger. Scroll to the bottom and open `Results View`.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach have me duplicating my endpoint in both the PS script and my C# code?  I'm looking to avoid this if possible.